# How to find gcd of two polynomials if a different field?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am trying to understand how to find the greatest common divisor of two polynomials in fields different that $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{Q}$. For example, how would be the procedure to calculate gcd of $x^3+2x+1$ and $x^3+2x^2+2$ in $\mathbb{F}_3[x]$?

Comment: We can also apply the division algorithm over $\mathbb{F}_3$. The polynomials are coprime.

Comment: Euclid's algorithm works in $k[x]$ for any field $k$. Note that "coprime" in that case means not that you end up with $1$ when applying the algorithm, but that you end up with _any_ non-zero constant term.

Comment: What is the defintion of $F_3$? is it the set $\{ 1,2,3 \}$ mod $3$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting better with this. In the field with three elements, we can change $2$ to $-1$ as needed.

Begin
$$ \frac{x^3 - x^2 - 1}{x^3 - x + 1}, $$
quotient = $1,$ remainder = $-x^2 + x + 1.$

$$ \frac{x^3 - x + 1}{-x^2 + x + 1}, $$
quotient = $-x-1,$ remainder = $-2x+2 = x-1.$

$$ \frac{-x^2 + x + 1}{x-1}, $$
quotient = $-x,$ remainder = $1.$

$$ \frac{x-1}{1}, $$
quotient = $x-1,$ remainder = $0.$

In the sense of continued fractions, which i prefer for bookkeeping, partial quotients
$$ 1, \; \; -x-1, \; \; -x, \; \;x-1 $$
Convergents
$$ \frac{0}{1}, \; \;  \frac{1}{0}, \; \; \frac{1}{1}, \; \;  \frac{-x}{-x-1}, \; \;  \frac{x^2 + 1}{x^2 + x + 1}, \; \; \frac{x^3 - x^2 - 1}{x^3 - x + 1}.  $$

Finally
$$ (x^2 + 1)(x^3 - x + 1) = x^5 + x^2 - x + 1, $$
$$  (x^2 + x + 1)(x^3 - x^2 - 1) = x^5 + x^2 - x - 1 $$

$$ (x^2 + 1)(x^3 - x + 1) -  (x^2 + x + 1)(x^3 - x^2 - 1) = 2 = - 1. $$